# Updating tables with a SQL Server linked to access linked to sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sharepoint-2007

I am running Access 2010 and Sharepoint 2007.

I have created an Access database. To this database I have linked 5 tables from an SQL Server. To this database I have also linked a Sharepoint list.

What I would like to do is update 5 fields on the Sharepoint list. Each of these fields would come from a different one of my tables from my SQL Server.

I have also written a simple query in my database that puts these 5 columns from the SQL Server together exactly how I want them uploaded into the 5 columns in my Sharepoint list.

Is it possible to update this Sharepoint list based on my query or fields in my tables? What is the best way to go about doing this?

I can not eliminate the use of the Access database and go directly from SQL to Sharepoint as I am required to run reports based on my Sharepoint list out of Access.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is the same as if you where using local access tables without SQL Server and without SharePoint.

You can create a update query, and update those fields based on the id. It just not quite clear how you plan to update the given columns. However, assume two tables such as tblSQLserver and tblSharePoint, you can go:

```
UPDATE tblSharePoint
INNER JOIN tblSQL ON tblSharePoint.ID = tblSQL.ID 
SET tblSharePoint.CompanyName = tblSQL.CompanyName
```

So, the above  would update all Company names from the SQL Server table to the SharePoint table based on them having the same ID. So standard Access update queries can be run this way.

However, if I was going to run several updates, it is not quite clear what ID column you going to join these tables on, I would consider using a reocrdset and VBA code. Note that these types of updates run VERY slow on SharePoint.